# How to open a chrome extension database .ldb

Tags: node.js, database, leveldb

How to open a chrome extension leveldb database.
I actually googled, but I didn't find anything worthwhile.

Tell me please how to open leveldb a database through any program with GUI, or at least a script in some programming language

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.